# RDS Memory Monitoring is almost full but nothing is happenning on the server

Tags: amazon-rds

I don't understand how to read the Memory monitoring graph.

[RDS Monitoring Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KepYj.png)

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

First, database engine itself consumes memory.

Second, data is usually cached and not pushed out of RAM until RDBMS needs to. There might be cached data from previous queries.

Comment: This doesn't really go far enough but it is essentially correct.  Between the OS cache and memory structures like the buffer pool in InnoDB, it's completely normal, even optimal/desirable, for an RDBMS that is warmed up but completely idle to have as little as 20% or even less of the system's memory remain free.  It would make no sense to evict data from memory that would just have to be loaded in from disk to serve a subsequent query.